# Setting Programmatic Actions for NSPopUpButton

Tags: macos, nsview, nspopupbutton

This is a very simple... confusing thought question. I'm a bit confused as to how calls work with NSObjects, and I can't seem to get this to work at all (despite being... what I assume, very simple).

I've create an `NSViewController` with a matching `.xib`. In the XIB is a label, a pop up button, and a regular button, shown below.

[image]

All I want, is for the button to reflect the selected number of the Pop Up Button. Easy enough to set up the first time in code, in the View Controller.

```
class Root: NSViewController {
    //MARK: IBs
    @IBOutlet weak var noOfImages: NSPopUpButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var genButton: NSButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
        genButton.title = "Generate \(noOfImages.selectedItem?.title) Image"
        noOfImages.autoenablesItems = false

        //Adding target
        noOfImages.target = self
        noOfImages.action = #selector(imageValueChanged(_:))
    }

    @objc func imageValueChanged(_ sender: NSPopUpButton) {
        print("print changed")
    }

}
```

Or so I think. My `imageValueChanged` function is never called. Ever. I've also tried changing the `@objc func` to a simple `IBAction`, and still - nothing.

Am I missing something glaringly obvious about getting an action to actually register? Is this a bug?

**EDITED**: Just to add - I tried connecting an action and selector to just the `NSButton` as well. Nothing. When I `sendAction` with the button, however, I get a response. I really have zero idea what is going on.

Comment: Did you connect the popup button object (defined in the .xib) to the outlet (defined in your swift file)? See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ConnectingObjectstoCode.html)

Comment: I did. I figured out that the issue was changing `contentView` to `contentViewControlller` in the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 0):

In the `AppDelegate`, be sure to render `contentViewController` and not `contentView`.